# How to write for an updated edition?

Tags: technical-writing, revision

I have a wargaming rulebook that I self-published over a decade ago, that has some interest around it. (Overall, the form is a combination of technical writing + creative design components.) I've been wanting to update to a second edition, but I run into some logistical roadblocks as I do so.

The original self-published book is in a word processor file, fairly carefully paginated, with art and tables, etc. The revised edition adds and changes a significant amount of stuff, moves pieces into different sections, and adds copious endnotes. I think part of the problem is that as I add stuff & change stuff I'm necessarily destroying the prior formatting of the book, which is distracting and painful. At this point I have a hacked-up document, scattered endnotes, lots of "TODO" notes and random blocks of possible-things-to-change, and it feels hard to make headway on the editing.

What's the best strategy for approaching a revision/update like this? Things I've considered:

- Get over it, and keep hacking the existing document, and clean it up later.
- Remove all the art and formatting so they're not distracting me, and reformat/replace art later (but note that certain tables are critical to the flow of the presentation).
- Strip everything out to a text-only format, e.g. Markdown, work on text in that form, and reformat the book separately (but note that Markdown isn't great at making the endnotes immediately visible/accessible when working on the document).

Answer (score 4):

If you write prose, never layout as you write. You don't want to be held up in your writing by having to make design descisions such as fiddling with whitespace to avoid orphans just to have to redo everything only because you later choose to move one paragraph to somewhere else in your text.

There is a reason why professionals are asked to submit unformatted manuscripts with the in-text illustrations at the end. Thinking about where to place illustrations is not your task (while you write).

If you make fundamental edits that change the whole layout of the text, the professional approach would be to write the revised text and then do a new layout. A good layouting approach (that uses some kind of markup* and global formatting rules) takes much less time than fiddling around in an existing layout.

---

* For example, defining a paragraph as "heading" in Word.

Comment: One thing maybe you could clarify in this answer: It sounds like reducing it to a purely text-only format like Markdown is _not_ recommended or required, correct?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Correct. But you want some way to mark the different types of paragraphs. Word processors like Microsoft Word hide the actual markup from the user, presenting only the formatted text to you. There is still markup "behind the surface".

Comment: Thanks, hoping you can explicate that in the answer with an edit.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Please read the footnote to my answer. It already contains that information.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't address that part of my question.

Comment: Since you want to redo the layout but not lose body text markup such as italics, you will need to find a way to remove all layout information but keep all body text markup information. When you copy/paste text, you never know what "invisible" information is transferred between WYSIWYG editors, so I would export to markedup plain text, remove all layouting markup manually (e.g. by search and replace) but keep all body text markup, then reimport into your editor. Much of the procedure will depend on what export and import formats your editor supports. I would probably use either Markup or HTML.

Comment: If you don't have any body text markup (e.g. no italics) or only a handful of instances of it, I would export to plain text and redo the italics manually. –– Anyway, you will want to go through plain text, because you will want to make sure that no markup information (such as page breaks, line breaks, word breaks etc.) is left that may mess with your new layout, especially if you want to provide a fluid format such as an ebook.